# How to integrate $\int\frac{\sin(kx)}{e^x}dx?$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

How would one integrate $$\int\sin(kx)e^{-x}dx, k\in\mathbb{R}?$$ I have tried integration by parts  $$\int\sin(kx)e^{-x}dx=$$

Comment: Try it out _twice_!

Answer (score 1):

Hint

$$\int\frac{\sin(kx)}{e^x}dx=Im\left(\int e^{-x+ikx}dx\right)$$